# How to substitute a substring delimited by separator in a specific position with sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed, substitution

I have a record like this:

`aaa|11|bcvdgsf|11|eyetwrt|11|kkjdksjk`

I would substitute the second occurrence of "11" with nother substring, for example `XX`. So the output would be

`aaa|11|bcvdgsf|XX|eyetwrt|11|kkjdksjk`

I tryed to use this command:

#`echo "z|11|a|11|b|11|" | sed 's/\(|11\{2\}\)/\|XX/'`

but record does not change

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sed+replac+second+occurence+in+line -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/ -> `Replacing the nth occurrence of a pattern in a line` -> `sed 's/11/XX/2'`. Learn regexes with https://regexcrossword.com/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try my (working) solution:

```
echo "z|11|a|11|b|11|" | sed -r 's/^([a-z]+\|11\|[a-z]+\|)(11)(.+)$/\1XX\3/'
```

Comment: hi, it works as well. thanks for your answer.

Comment: Glad to have helped you. Please kindly upvote it if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this to say "replace the second instance of `11` delimited by word boundaries on both sides with `XX`:"

```sh
$ sed 's/\b11\b/XX/2' <<< 'aaa|11|bcvdgsf|11|eyetwrt|11|kkjdksjk'
aaa|11|bcvdgsf|XX|eyetwrt|11|kkjdksjk
```

This requires GNU sed for `\b` support.

Comment: Thanks. It works.  I was thinking about how tell to 'sed' to switch position by '|' delimeter, but '\b' i see that do this by itself.  I have to deepen into '-b' option. Thanks

Comment: @AlessandroBarca `\b` will change even if a field contains data like `11.2` or `(11)`.

Answer (score 1):

If only whole field has to be matched:

```sh
$ cat ip.txt
z|11|a|11|b|11|
aaa|11|bcvdgsf|11|eyetwrt|11|kkjdksjk
11|11.2|abc|11|cca
11||11
11|11|ac
a|11|asd|11

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
       {c=0; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i=="11" && ++c==2) $i="XX"}
       1' ip.txt
z|11|a|XX|b|11|
aaa|11|bcvdgsf|XX|eyetwrt|11|kkjdksjk
11|11.2|abc|XX|cca
11||XX
11|XX|ac
a|11|asd|XX
```

- `FS=OFS="|"` use `|` as input and output field separator
- `c=0` initialize counter for every line
- `for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)` to loop over all input fields
- `$i=="11" && ++c==2` if field content is exactly `11`, increment counter and check if it is the second match
- `$i="XX"` change field content as needed
- `1` idiomatic way to print `$0`

Similar logic with `perl` using lookarounds to match field boundary:

```sh
perl -lpe '$c=0; s/(?<![^|])11(?![^|])/++$c==2 ? "XX" : $&/ge'
```